# Image gallery with different image sizes in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, image-gallery

I have two images with two different size. I am using  bootstrap in my project.  But I cant place the images together which looks like both have same dimension. I have gone through similar questions and tried a lot. Please help me to sort this out.

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/2048x1536" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2048x1536" alt="Nature">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/1280x720" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x720" alt="Nature">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css is

```
.thumbnail img {
height:250px;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: try to use images as a background to the `<a>` with some height

Comment: I dont seems to get your question here the images are place side by side

Comment: me too the img side by side with same width/height

Comment: @Ajzz see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uhLfLe83/  maybe you miss some script

Comment: @לבני מלכה pls go through this link - alamoudilogistics.com/test/sample.html

Comment: @Ajzz do you want to set `height:250px` ??

Comment: you have to use `!important` to prevent ovveride 
:    `height: 250px!important;`

Comment: @Ajzz tell me if `!important` helps!!!

Comment: yeah important worked.thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting the picture as background-image for the 'div' tag and setting value of 'background-position' as 'stretch'.

Said that, if the images are of different resolution and you fit them into the same-size container it might look pixelated at times.